# Google maps API - not accepting values from geocode

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-geocoder

I am trying to implement the Google API maps in my javascript. Based on an address, I want to get the corresponding latitude/longitude and show a map on this location. When I hardcode the location, it works. When I use the values from the geocoder, the map is empty. Here is the code:

```
<script>
     function initMap() {
         var loc = [];
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         var address = "New York"; 

         geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                 loc[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                 alert(loc); 

             } else {
                 alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
             }
         });


         // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: loc[0], lng: loc[1] },
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 8
    });
}

              </script>
```

The alert(loc) function displays the correct latitude and longitude values, but the map still seems to be empty. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geocoder.geocode()` works asynchronously. That means you should put map initialization inside the callback function. Currently you initialize the map before the geocoder callback is triggered.

```
function initMap() {
     var map;
     var loc = [];
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var address = "New York"; 

     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             loc[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
             //alert(loc); 

             // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
               {
                   center: { lat: loc[0], lng: loc[1] },
                   scrollwheel: false,
                   zoom: 8
               });

         } else {
             alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
         }
     });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Geocode API recently changed something. They are not accepting # in address